# Leak in basement - should I be concerned?

Tags: drywall, basement, leak, mold

I recently moved into a brand new apartment building. I have a ground floor duplex (downstairs is below ground) and shortly after moving in I noticed there was something leaking into the wall downstairs. It seemed to happen only after heavy rains so after some investigation they determined that they needed to replace the water drainage system outside the building. They finished that and now are replacing the drywall & insulation downstairs - basically tearing up drywall a couple feet at a time and feeling the insulation and if it's wet they're tearing it out and replacing.

My question is: how concerned should I be about this? They assured me there's no reason to worry about mold because of the materials used (something about special drywall for basements) but obviously it's in their interest to do as little as possible. I also noticed some water damage (brown edges) on the floor (flat tile or maybe it's a tile-looking laminate?) right where it meets the wall - should I be concerned that the floor (or baseboards I suppose) I'm walking on is deteriorating? I'm out of my element and I'm not sure I can trust what management says because there's a bit of a conflict of interest.

Comment: Aren't you on a slab? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: i guess what i'm asking is - are they doing the right things here? are there things i don't know about that i should worry about?

Comment: It sounds like they are doing it correctly. Repairing the drainage issue first. Since they are replacing the Sheetrock (possibly with green board) rather than plain Sheetrock they are going above and beyond in my opinion. If the flooring was slightly discolored but dried and there is no mold it two will probably be fine. If it was sewage I would be concerned but rain water not so much. It sounds like they are doing a good job and there is nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Water damage to the floor in a basement is cosmetic only, unless the floor is totally rotten and literally crumbles under your feet. If you're worried about mold, you need to hire a mold remediation company, to do a mold inspection. Their written report will give you some leverage when dealing with your landlord and making sure they do proper repairs, if there is indeed mold in there. Mold inspection can easily be several hundred dollars, though. Also, they may need to open up walls, so better do it before the repairs are complete.

Comment: @EdBeal if you want to post your response as an answer i'll gladly accept it. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested; It sounds like they are doing it correctly. Repairing the drainage issue first. Since they are replacing the Sheetrock (possibly with green board) rather than plain Sheetrock they are going above and beyond in my opinion. If the flooring was slightly discolored but dried and there is no mold it two will probably be fine. If it was sewage I would be concerned but rain water not so much. It sounds like they are doing a good job and there is nothing to be worried about.